# python dictionary convert to json not as expected

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I am using Django 1.8 and python 2.7. I want to parse some data from my database(sqlite3) to a JSON format.

view.py:

```
def json_view(request):
    maps = Maps.objects.filter(data_id=3).values('ciudad', 'latitud', 'longitud')
    userPos = json.dumps(list(maps))
    return JsonResponse({'userPosView': userPos})
```

When I access via browser to my view I get:

```
{"userPosView": "[{\"latitud\": \"12.1363889\", \"ciudad\": \"Manague\", \"longitud\": \"-86.2513889\"}]"}
```

The problem is that userPosView looks like the key and the rest as a single value of userPosView

```
"[{\"latitud\": \"12.1363889\", \"ciudad\": \"Manague\", \"longitud\": \"-86.2513889\"}]".
```

I would be grateful if somebody could help me because I can not access to the values of latitude and longitude on my JSON object.

Comment: You can access them with json["userPosView"]["latitud"] You dont like that?

Comment: I'd just like to note that the backslashes `\"latitud\"` means that this is being turned into JSON twice, and JSON Parsers won't pick this up as real JSON. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you adding all the JSON inside userPosView?

```
 return JsonResponse({'userPosView': userPos})
```

You could just return the created dump like this

```
return JsonResponse(userPos)
```

Comment: If I do that, I have an error In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.

Comment: so I add safe=False, but I get the same result as always: all the values looks like a single one

Comment: As bruno said JsonResponse already encodes to JSON, try returning just the map, like this, return JsonResponse(maps)

Answer (score 2):

`JsonResponse()` alreday takes care of encoding it's content to json, so you end up with a double encoding of your data - one in your own code, the second in `JsonResponse`. The fix is simple: don't manually encode your data to json before passing it to `JsonResponse`:

```
def json_view(request):
    maps = Maps.objects.filter(data_id=3).values('ciudad', 'latitud', 'longitud')

    return JsonResponse({'userPosView': list(maps)})
```